# Closing balance of various financial Years using DAX

Tags: dax

I have to generate report to  show active Number of Persons during financial year from  Apr-01 to Mar-31 .  I tried closing, opening balance Year of DAX  queries .   I am not getting expected Result.

please help  in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem ca be this measure:

```
Measure:=CALCULATE(sum([valore]);DATESYTD(DimTime[data];"04-01");ALL(DimTime[data]))
```

In the DATESYTD you have to select your column date and the start period of your Fiscal year ( for april "04-01" ) This formula work like a Year to date.

If you want previous year you have to do:

```
CALcULATE (
    sum([valore]),
    DATEADD (DATESYTD(DimTime[data];"04-01")), -1, YEAR ),
    ALL (DimTime)
)
```

Comment: Above DAX is  populating year End values Q4  but for Current year , Latest Quarter is not populated.